# Why are my Branch metrics different on my dashboard and the exported CSV file?

Tags: branch.io

I'm tracking some custom events on Branch and I usually go to the sources page to see the number of times a click has happened. Recently, I went to the live events view and exported the events from there. It turned out that the metrics did not tally with what I found on the dashboard. Some events that only had about 70 clicks on the dashboard had over 1000 in the csv file. Which one is more accurate? Am I using the sources page wrong?

Comment: Make sure the data you fetch by exporting the clicks from the CSV and data you are referring to have the same time range. Also, the exported CSV has clicks from all links possible in the same time range. While source analytics screen shows the clicks segregated by the campaign. Make sure you are looking at the same campaign, feature, etc. in the exported clicks as shown on the Source Analytics page.

Comment: Are you saying that the exported CSV sums up the number of clicks for feature, campaign, tags, etc?? My app does not do any campaigns or anything. I basically just send custom events to the dashboard. I've checked the time range thing and it is not an issue of the time range.

Comment: The exported CSV has all the clicks for your Branch links during that time range. The Source analytics shows analytics during the time range selected but segregates them by campaigns.

Comment: I'm getting the same number of events for Campaign, Tags, Stage, Channel and Feature. I did not configure any form of custom campaign. My question now is: Does the exported CSV sum up the clicks for  Campaign, Tags, Stage, Channel and Feature ?? Also, does the exported CSV include both live and test data??? Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: where are you exporting the clicks from? Liveview or Quick links page. If you are exporting from the 'Clicks' tab on Liveview tab you will get a list of individual clicks it will not sum up the clicks at all. Also, the exported CSV will contain clicks only for the Live App or the Test App depending on where you exported it from. It will never contain both clicks.

Comment: I exported from the 'Events' tab on the Liveview tab. I'm talking about custom events here.

Comment: If you exported the Events from the Events tab, it just shows the custom events fired. It does not give any information about the clicks. If you still have issues understanding the analytics on the dashboard, you could write to `integrations@branch.io`.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not give information about the clicks?? Doesn't it give an amount for the number of times a custom event was triggered??
When I say clicks here, I'm talking about for custom events not link clicks.

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh

Comment: that is correct when you export the events it will tell you a list of all the events that have been triggered i.e. installs, opens, referred sessions, custom events etc.

Answer (score 0):

The information displayed in the Liveview section of the dashboard is intended for use by developers needing to see a raw log of what Branch's systems are seeing. This data is the raw material that Branch's internal data pipelines consume to produce the analytics reports in other portions of the dashboard.

Branch's internal systems do quite a bit of cleanup on the raw Liveview data before it is made availble for reports that appear elsewhere on the dashboard. So to address your question:

- The Liveview data is an accurate reflection of what Branch's systems are seeing
- The Sources report shows Branch's interpretation of the story that is being told by the raw Liveview data

Use Liveview only for troubleshooting integration issues, rely on the other dashboard reports for analytics.